# How to delete array element with Null value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below array that i retrieve from Db, now if any of this array element has no value i want to remove the array element and reindex the array, i try the beow code but it didn't work

```
    array name is $photo
     Array
   (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [photo1] => uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg
            [photo2] => 
            [photo3] => uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg
            [photo4] => 
            [photo5] => 
            [photo6] => uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg
            [photo7] => 
            [photo8] => 
            [photo9] => 
            [photo10] => 
            [photo11] => 
            [photo12] => 
            [photo13] => 
            [photo14] => 
            [photo15] => 
            [photo16] => 
            [photo17] => 
            [photo18] => 
            [photo19] => 
            [photo20] => 
        )

      )
```

I tried this code

```
foreach ($photo as $key => $value) {
       if(array_key_exists($key, $photo) && is_null($photo[$key])) {
           unset($photo[$key]); 
        }
```

i want my result to be something like

```
$photo =([photo1]=>uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg
           [photo3]=>uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg
           [photo6]=>uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg);
```

any help on this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is an array in an array, you still need at least a loop, so you might go with that code and extend it using array_filter. Only array_filter will not work proper.

```
<?php

$var = [
    [
        'photo1'  => 'uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg',
        'photo2'  => null,
        'photo3'  => 'uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg',
        'photo4'  => null,
        'photo5'  => null,
        'photo6'  => 'uploads/_cgL-CMy7JVHxds.jpg',
        'photo7'  => null,
        'photo8'  => null,
        'photo9'  => null,
        'photo10' => null,
        'photo11' => null,
        'photo12' => null,
        'photo13' => null,
        'photo14' => null,
        'photo15' => null,
        'photo16' => null,
        'photo17' => null,
        'photo18' => null,
        'photo19' => null,
        'photo20' => null,
    ],
];

foreach ($var as $key => $photos) {
    foreach ($photos as $photoId => $path) {
        if (empty($path)) {
            unset ($var[$key][$photoId]);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Christian a really big thanks, you've just  saved my day, i only try to loop through the array once and also use array_filter, but your code work so perfectly

Comment: array_filter might be faster, but at this point it's a bit like micro-optimization...

Answer (score 0):

you don't need that 
there is

```
array_filter()
```

which will unset all the empty values in your array [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r( array_filter( $photo ));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!